# Incrementing Dynamic Prototypes crashes XCode 4.5.1

Tags: xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I am creating a scene in a `UIStoryboard` with a `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` that is 44 points high. My plan was to have 4 or 5 Dynamic-Prototype cells, and load the appropriate one at run time. Essentially allow myself to have a dynamic section of my view.

The problem that I'm having is that when I try to increment the # of dynamic prototypes beyond 1, XCode (4.5.1) crashes on me.  Has anyone encountered this before, and what did you do to work around it?

My first thought is to simply make the `UITableView` larger in the storyboard, and resize it at runtime, but that just feels wrong.

I've added a simple project to github with an example. Open in XCode 4.5.1, find the tableview in the storyboard and increment the dynamic-prototypes.
[GitHub Project: https://github.com/mkernahan/TableViewCrashesXCode](https://github.com/mkernahan/TableViewCrashesXCode)

Note that my build target is set to 5.0 (6.0 doesn't make a difference though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build target can surely make difference if you are using `Constrains`, you need to uncheck `Use Autolayout` and try

Comment: Well, this does work with build target of both 5.0 and 6.0.  Sadly it means you can't use constraints on the entire storyboard if you have this problem.  So this solves it for me since I need to target 5.0, but looks to be a bug in XCode for 6.0

Comment: Well, looks like no one has any suggestions with `Autolayout` enabled. Thanks for the help!